# {{skin url=""}} is removed

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.2.4, cms-pages, template-directive

I am facing a problem, whenever I am editing CMS page by using editor that time all of the `{{skin url=''}}` is being removed automatically.

Can anyone please advice me some solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible only if you have some mistake in HTML or mistake using quote.

If you write like this :

```
<a href="{{skin url=""}}"> OR < a href='{{skin url=''}}'>
```

then its not valid in editor.
Instead of this you have to write like :

```
<a href="{{skin url=''}}"> OR < a href='{{skin url=""}}'>
```